# Angular2: Contents of collection 'x' are updated, but never queried.?

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm

Variables that are defined, but not used in **.ts** file rather in **template**, show this warning on hover in **WebStorm**.

> Unused field X [more...](http://#) `(CTRL + F1)`
>
> Contents of collection 'x' are updated, but never queried.[more...](http://#) `(CTRL + F1)`

Is it **TSLint** or **WebStorm**? because it's just a warning.

Should I just ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I just ignore it?

Its webstorm. It will give a lot of similar *helpful* warning. I've learnt to ignore them .. especially if you are using TypeScript (which has great error detection built in anyways).

Comment: There is a workaround, public identifiers don't give that `Unsused` warning. But it might not be a good one.

Comment: If it wasn't webstorm, there is always a "TSLint:" prefix for the error message :)